# web app button read and another record does not work

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am trying to make a web application that presents a button to start a new record, which performs a record search to bring the information in a form, which must be filled out and saved, with a Save button.
The button to start performs the registry search, fetches the data and presents a form, but the Save button does not work.

CODE.GS

```js
function doGet (e) {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}

function procesaFormDatosPersona(e){
    var ultimaFilaDatos = e.ultimaFilaDatos;
    var email = e.email;
    var fecha_contacto = e.fecha_contacto;
    var resultado = e.resultado;
    var hojaCalculo = SpreadsheetApp.openById("-- ID --");
    var hojaDatos = hojaCalculo.getSheetByName('REGISTROS');
    hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFilaDatos, 30).setValue(email);
    hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFilaDatos, 5).setValue(fecha_contacto);
    hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFilaDatos, 11).setValue(resultado);
}

function Inicio()
{
    var hojaCalculo = SpreadsheetApp.openById("-- ID --");
    var hojaDatos = hojaCalculo.getSheetByName('REGISTROS');
    var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();   
    var numRows = hojaDatos.getLastRow();
    var data_mg = hojaDatos.getRange(1, 9, numRows).getValues();
    var data = hojaDatos.getRange(1, 1, numRows).getValues();
    for(var i = data.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
      if ((data[i][0] != null && data[i][0] != "") && ( data_mg[i][0] == "")){
        var ultimaFilaDatos = i + 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    hojaDatos.getRange(ultimaFilaDatos, 9).setValue(email);
   
    var string = "";
    string += "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"ultimaFilaDatos\" name=\"ultimaFilaDatos\" value=\"" + ultimaFilaDatos + "\">";
    string += "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"email\" name=\"email\" value=\"" + email + "\">";
    string += "Ejecutivo :" + email + "</br>";
    string += "Fecha Contacto : <input type=\"date\" id=\"fecha_contacto\" name=\"fecha_contacto\" title=\"Fecha Contacto\" > <br>";
    string += "Resultado : <input type=\"text\" id=\"resultado\" name=\"resultado\" title=\"Resultado\" > <br>";
    string += "<button class=\"action\" id=\"guardar\" type=\"submit\" >Guardar</button>";
    string += "<input type=\"reset\">";
       
  return string;
}
```

INDEX.HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
  function procesaFormulario(){
    google.script.run.procesaFormDatosPersona(document.forms[0]);
   }
  function Response(string){
       document.getElementsByName("ejemplo")[0].innerHTML = string;
   }
  function InitWeb(){
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(Response).Inicio();
   }
</script>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body >
  <button class="action" id="nuevo" type="button" onclick="InitWeb()">Nuevo Registro</button>
  
  <form id="datosPersona" name="datosPersona" onsubmit="procesaFormulario()">
  
      <div name='ejemplo' id="cuerpo" ></div>
  
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read - [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication). If after reading it you still need help replace your current code by a [mcve].

Comment: I cannot understand about `the Save button does not work.`. Can you explain about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike The save button is included in the server side code as "guardar" (the Spanish word for save). Esteban: Si vas incluir cosas en Español considera publicar tu pregunta en [es.so], de lo contrario es mejor que al menos traduzcas al inglés a lo que estás haciendo referencia.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for your support. From your comment, I could understand "save" is "guardar" as the Spanish word.

Comment: @Tanaike More specífically this is the referred statement : `string += "<button class=\"action\" id=\"guardar\" type=\"submit\" >Guardar</button>";`

Comment: Link to question on [es.so] -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/393267/65

Comment: @Tanaike, in english : string += `"<button class=\"action\" id=\"save\" type=\"submit\" >Save</button>";`